# Fitnesse test fails with linq datacontext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

My fitnesse tests fail with linq datacontext.  I already tried adding a suite.config and then app config to my c:\fitnesse folder - where the .jar file is.

I added `-c` option `c:\Fitnesse\suite.config` to the command section on the test page. Here's the `suite.config` file: `c:\fitnesse\myapp.config ^.svn$`

Here's the myapp.config file:

The test still fails here:

```
public MyDataContext() : 
    base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString, 
         mappingSource
    ) 
{ 
    OnCreated(); 
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could call other constructors, perhaps find a constructor that doesn't hit the config?  Or... it's a partial class so you can add a constructor that doesn't hit the config if you don't already have one you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use the -a option:

http://www.syterra.com/Fit/AppConfigFile.html

There's a bug in the suite config code for app config files - will be fixed in the next release.